# Why am I getting "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/{reponame}/tags/list: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"?

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, aws-ecr, docker-java

### Summary

I am trying to use the `docker-java` library but I am running into a problem when I try to pull an image. I am trying to pull from a private repository on ECR.

### What I have tried

Much of the implementation I have been trying has come from the following question:
[Pulling image from Amazon ECR using docker-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099527/pulling-image-from-amazon-ecr-using-docker-java#40204788)

The difference being that I am implementing it in Kotlin. I am developing on MacOS.

I am able to login fine as I get a "Login Succeeded" when I execute `dockerClient.authCmd()`.

### Code

```
        val awsCredentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider = 
                DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()
        val ecrClient = AmazonECRClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2)
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build()

        val getAuthTokenRequest = GetAuthorizationTokenRequest()
        val registryIds = ArrayList<String>()
        registryIds.add(registryId)
        getAuthTokenRequest.setRegistryIds(registryIds)

        val getAuthTokenResult = ecrClient.getAuthorizationToken(getAuthTokenRequest)
        val authData = getAuthTokenResult.authorizationData[0]
        val userPassword = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decode(authData.authorizationToken))
        val user = userPassword.substring(0, userPassword.indexOf(":"))
        val password = userPassword.substring(userPassword.indexOf(":")+1)

        val config = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder()
            config.withDockerTlsVerify(false)
            config.withRegistryUsername(user)
            config.withRegistryPassword(password)
            config.withRegistryUrl(authData.proxyEndpoint)
            config.build()

        //Docker client
        val dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance(config)
            .withDockerCmdExecFactory(JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory())
            .build()

        val response = dockerClient.authCmd().exec()
        println(response.status)

        val pullImageCmd = dockerClient
                .pullImageCmd(nameOfRepository)
                .withAuthConfig(dockerClient.authConfig())
                .withRepository(nameOfRepository)

        pullImageCmd
                .exec(PullImageResultCallback())
                .awaitCompletion()
```

### Result

I and up getting the following error:

`Caused by: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: {"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/{name_of_repo}/tags/list: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}`

Should `registry-1.docker.io/v2/` in the URI not be my own repo?
Would someone be able to shed some light on the issue I am having?

Comment: probably because you've used an incorrect username or password, or because you don't have the right to login

Comment: The credentials are being picked up from the `~/.aws/credentials` file on my machine the way I would do it from the command line. I am able to login successfully with the auth command which uses the correct registry: `https://{name_of_registry}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/`. I tried entering an invalid password to confirmed and it fails with a 400 Bad Request. When the pullImageCmd is called, should that not be calling `https://{name_of_registry}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/{name_of_repo}/tags/list`